# Wordpress XMLRPC not working for all website

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website which post to two different Wordpress websites using XMLRPC. It is working fine for one and local as well but for the second it's posting and I got no response.

Site Details:
1st website like http://blog.mysite1.com (Working Fine),
2nd website like http://mysite2.com/blog (No Response)

Both websites are hosted on a different server. Can anyone tell me is there is any HTACCESS setting that prevent XMLPRC posting or any Wordpress plugin that might be a problem for the API.

I am using IXR_Library.php to create and edit blogs.

I am using the following function to check the connectivity of the API

```
function sayHello()
{
    $params = array();
    return $this->send_request('demo.sayHello',$params);
}
```

It returns 'Hello' for first website and Nothing for the secong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your server is missing PHP-XML.

The commands below are determined in part by your package manager. 
I use **yum** because that's what I learned first. 
I beleive Ubuntu distrabutions use **apt-get**

Here is how to fix it.

---

SSH into your server and run the following command.

```
yum install php-xml or apt-get install php-xml
```

Restart apache web server:

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: But when I hit the following URL to test, http://www.mysite2.com/blog/xmlrpc.php it says "XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only." and it was working fine earlier and now with no response. I just update Wordpress to 3.7.1 and some plugin as well, i tried to deactivate some plugin as well. Still same issue.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood your question. I would deactivate all plugins and set debug = true in wp-config. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks